# What modules does Moose render useless, or are incompatible with modern Perl?

Tags: perl

Given these assumptions:

- Your codebase is using [`Moose.pm`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose)
- Minor changes in implementations do not warrant having conflicting functionality

What modules would you **not** want to see, by the very fact that Moose does that functionality better? This is for my recently released [nextgen::blacklist](http://github.com/EvanCarroll/nextgen/blob/master/lib/nextgen/blacklist.pm) I'll go first:

- [NEXT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/NEXT)
- [SUPER](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SUPER)
- [base](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/base) / [parent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/parent)
- [mixin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/mixin)
- [fields](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/fields)
- All of the [Class::Accessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class%3a%3aAccessor) stuff

Preferably, we keep these to modules people *use* but shouldn't. If the module isn't used by [one author other than the creator](http://deps.cpantesters.org/) then I don't really care.

Comment: It's not just Class::Accessor; there are a dozen or more similar modules of various vintage

Answer (score 0):

hanekomu collected and compared accessor generating classes: http://hanekomu.at/blog/dev/20081101-1258-dissecting_the_moose_4-benchmarking_accessor_generators-accessors_only.html

There are a number of Moose work-alikes: [Mouse](http://p3rl.org/Mouse), [Coat](http://p3rl.org/Coat), [Gloom](http://p3rl.org/Gloom), [Mousse](http://p3rl.org/Mousse)

Comment: Mouse and Mousse aren't really lookalikes as much as different implementations of (subsets of) Moose designed for particular system constraints.